# git complains about untracked file

Tags: git, github

I have two branches:

```
-- feature
-- master
```

I used to work on **feature** branch. Then, I changed to **master** branch by `git checkout master`. After I worked on master, I run `git status` , which shows me the following:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 38 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   MyProject/school.java
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   MyProject/other/proj.properties
```

I decide to omit the changes I made on `MyProject/school.java` , so I run:

`git checkout MyProject/school.java` , it works well.

At this point, I run `git checkout feature` to go back to `feature` branch, but I got the following error message:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    MyProject/other/proj.properties
```

- Why git complains about **untracked** file `MyProject/other/proj.properties` when I switch to another branch?
- How to get rid of it? I would like to go back to `feature` branch without changing anything on `master`

I tried git rm --cached MyProject/other/proj.properties but I got the following error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'MyProject/other/proj.properties' did not match any files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, that the file is tracked in the `feature` branch, but not in `master`.
So the the file in `master` would be overwritten with the one in `feature` by the checkout and you would loose your changes.

Git recognizes that and prevents you from loosing the changes in the untracked file.

Edit: If the changes in that file can be removed, just delete the file. You do not need `git rm` as the file is not tracked.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So, how could I revert back to the state before I switched to master branch? I mean I would like to go back to feature branch without changing anything on master...

Comment: I understand, that you do not want to commit the `proj.properties` file. If that is correct, just remove the file. As it is not tracked, you have to use `rm` (not `git rm`).